# How to pass these type of cookies which contains date , path and some other data to a request in Python

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

So, basically this is the data

```
data =  "wm_ul_plus=INACTIVE|1613381571686; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Mon, 14 Feb 2022 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; SameSite=LAX; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/auth=MTAyOTYyMDE4RUUxlsaiphCIYphVuNp1cW8dYFFyMJIbZ8DpbWT8qFqXUDp9UK0SuJbhcel7WWkve5Rje21UFFM0bpxMqABtRTreKh7yCzxu8zVUwgzKsi52faNy4xK57I8j8gR%2FH852oHOs%2FstByN418DB3KSmMotPVleFVli5P1islDQzG7NvR4D%2FWel8G5u4D%2FKZuF1GZ0lpexIPdqnQwv7yAOsfFnWxVon1qX0ChQbDsykETs9jg9b5uIWpUVgkjQM%2F2HhqZcy8EOh6rgyD2lIWedWfYuiCmiCCv7uWeLT7owCHMkcJn5z6CDUQq0VRZxYrvBKWfudWdVmyzjyYG1ezlt%2BK%2FXzVveqGzNst19qXpVJMKowcGagQ%2BHDIopDoHbqbNGWhqdr0cAS%2B8b8QaKTuPRQvC8A%3D%3D; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Mon, 14 Feb 2022 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; HttpOnly; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/rtoken=MDgyNTUyMDE4cvAeVJ1s78Vnw4eesakndgcpAMTqAgcZzWhFeUMjJIkVESjrGL3t0ar6VME0rt5lWm2XnQufGVK4GchMVN9rTooMGd6hdQrncJnF4VUykW2GPdOrmoVdnaSnkEaB1oxkrM8WSQCJm4CKPwlXkTpf9CNNbTHRvTAft1QZSfcthEl%2Bfli9I6HKjyyL%2BM%2F1vtiKOONMAYP1o3Jpf83qBCUd35qPky0K6hHbyYd6PaYhlqIGlcPPS8R00qN%2BhNiLcApQIcu5eoH0LLfpaagTy7Xeje99cBiCQvaFuqLDzwZsMdrJTVL1F4AGdny%2FqrbGRms%2FRAaBsGXYjXIWyIkbC104F2Y%2FJLJ5JsiMjD6VOKSTwZJ7fXmi3hvYzjb4clXbEkUbUMdZbTmJW1qBxQgwbE78Pw%3D%3D; Max-Age=2592000; Expires=Tue, 16 Mar 2021 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/SPID=d6266476ca903157e0e660433a3aa7346bca664f9a9490400cc20c8032ae3e4d4029a5d079c4aac3e3934eede0ce5161wmjet; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Mon, 14 Feb 2022 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; HttpOnly; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/CID=f20e6b0e-dfe8-1a52-e044-001517f43a86; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Mon, 14 Feb 2022 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/hasCID=1; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Mon, 14 Feb 2022 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/customer=%7B%22firstName%22%3A%22francine%22%2C%22lastNameInitial%22%3A%22b%22%2C%22rememberme%22%3Atrue%7D; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Mon, 14 Feb 2022 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/type=REGISTERED; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Mon, 14 Feb 2022 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; HttpOnly; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/WMP=4; Max-Age=15552000; Expires=Fri, 13 Aug 2021 09:32:51 GMT; SameSite=Lax; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/slToken=x; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; SameSite=Strict; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/oneapp_customer=true; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Mon, 14 Feb 2022 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/TB_Latency_Tracker_100=1; Path=/; Domain=walmart.com; Expires=Mon, 15 Feb 2021 09:32:51 GMT; Max-Age=86400/,/TB_Navigation_Preload_01=1; Path=/; Domain=walmart.com; Expires=Mon, 15 Feb 2021 09:32:51 GMT; Max-Age=86400/,/TB_SFOU-100=; Path=/; Domain=walmart.com; Expires=Mon, 15 Feb 2021 09:32:51 GMT; Max-Age=86400/,/TB_DC_Flap_Test=0; Path=/; Domain=walmart.com; Expires=Sun, 14 Feb 2021 10:32:51 GMT; Max-Age=3600/,/vtc=Rhk42QOR0Wmu4R452HwYkE;Path=/;Domain=.walmart.com;Expires=Fri, 14 Feb 2031 21:32:51 GMT;Max-Age=315576000/,/bstc=Rhk42QOR0Wmu4R452HwYkE;Path=/;Domain=.walmart.com;Expires=Sun, 14 Feb 2021 10:02:51 GMT;Max-Age=1800/,/mobileweb=0; Path=/; Domain=walmart.com; Expires=Sun, 14 Feb 2021 10:02:51 GMT; Max-Age=1800/,/xpa=1wERM|5Z16k|bfyXO|np1Pu|piMFH; Path=/; Domain=walmart.com; Expires=Sun, 14 Feb 2021 10:02:51 GMT; Max-Age=1800/,/xpm=0%2B1613295171%2BRhk42QOR0Wmu4R452HwYkE~%2B0; Path=/; Domain=walmart.com; Expires=Sun, 14 Feb 2021 10:02:51 GMT; Max-Age=1800/,/exp-ck=bfyXO1; Path=/; Domain=walmart.com; Expires=Sun, 14 Feb 2021 10:02:51 GMT; Max-Age=1800/,/TS01b0be75=01538efd7cd0dba2bd4710700bc152f3514f1a97eb0b905564c5e97a2308f494c0a937c315a9f337bd1769571591556833993841c0; Path=/; Domain=.www.walmart.com/,/TS013ed49a=01538efd7cd0dba2bd4710700bc152f3514f1a97eb0b905564c5e97a2308f494c0a937c315a9f337bd1769571591556833993841c0; path=/; domain=walmart.com"
```

How can we convert this data to a normal dict of key and value. I tried to look some repeating pairs which divides them but no use.

Also, Can we this whole data to send a request directly?

***EDIT***

I just manually did it.

```py
def find_between(s, first, last):
    try:
        start = s.index(first) + len(first)
        end = s.index(last, start)
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return False

data =  "wm_ul_plus=INACTIVE|1613381571686; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Mon, 14 Feb 2022 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; SameSite=LAX; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/auth=MTAyOTYyMDE4RUUxlsaiphCIYphVuNp1cW8dYFFyMJIbZ8DpbWT8qFqXUDp9UK0SuJbhcel7WWkve5Rje21UFFM0bpxMqABtRTreKh7yCzxu8zVUwgzKsi52faNy4xK57I8j8gR%2FH852oHOs%2FstByN418DB3KSmMotPVleFVli5P1islDQzG7NvR4D%2FWel8G5u4D%2FKZuF1GZ0lpexIPdqnQwv7yAOsfFnWxVon1qX0ChQbDsykETs9jg9b5uIWpUVgkjQM%2F2HhqZcy8EOh6rgyD2lIWedWfYuiCmiCCv7uWeLT7owCHMkcJn5z6CDUQq0VRZxYrvBKWfudWdVmyzjyYG1ezlt%2BK%2FXzVveqGzNst19qXpVJMKowcGagQ%2BHDIopDoHbqbNGWhqdr0cAS%2B8b8QaKTuPRQvC8A%3D%3D; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Mon, 14 Feb 2022 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; HttpOnly; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/rtoken=MDgyNTUyMDE4cvAeVJ1s78Vnw4eesakndgcpAMTqAgcZzWhFeUMjJIkVESjrGL3t0ar6VME0rt5lWm2XnQufGVK4GchMVN9rTooMGd6hdQrncJnF4VUykW2GPdOrmoVdnaSnkEaB1oxkrM8WSQCJm4CKPwlXkTpf9CNNbTHRvTAft1QZSfcthEl%2Bfli9I6HKjyyL%2BM%2F1vtiKOONMAYP1o3Jpf83qBCUd35qPky0K6hHbyYd6PaYhlqIGlcPPS8R00qN%2BhNiLcApQIcu5eoH0LLfpaagTy7Xeje99cBiCQvaFuqLDzwZsMdrJTVL1F4AGdny%2FqrbGRms%2FRAaBsGXYjXIWyIkbC104F2Y%2FJLJ5JsiMjD6VOKSTwZJ7fXmi3hvYzjb4clXbEkUbUMdZbTmJW1qBxQgwbE78Pw%3D%3D; Max-Age=2592000; Expires=Tue, 16 Mar 2021 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/SPID=d6266476ca903157e0e660433a3aa7346bca664f9a9490400cc20c8032ae3e4d4029a5d079c4aac3e3934eede0ce5161wmjet; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Mon, 14 Feb 2022 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; HttpOnly; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/CID=f20e6b0e-dfe8-1a52-e044-001517f43a86; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Mon, 14 Feb 2022 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/hasCID=1; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Mon, 14 Feb 2022 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/customer=%7B%22firstName%22%3A%22francine%22%2C%22lastNameInitial%22%3A%22b%22%2C%22rememberme%22%3Atrue%7D; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Mon, 14 Feb 2022 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/type=REGISTERED; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Mon, 14 Feb 2022 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; HttpOnly; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/WMP=4; Max-Age=15552000; Expires=Fri, 13 Aug 2021 09:32:51 GMT; SameSite=Lax; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/slToken=x; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; SameSite=Strict; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/oneapp_customer=true; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Mon, 14 Feb 2022 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/TB_Latency_Tracker_100=1; Path=/; Domain=walmart.com; Expires=Mon, 15 Feb 2021 09:32:51 GMT; Max-Age=86400/,/TB_Navigation_Preload_01=1; Path=/; Domain=walmart.com; Expires=Mon, 15 Feb 2021 09:32:51 GMT; Max-Age=86400/,/TB_SFOU-100=; Path=/; Domain=walmart.com; Expires=Mon, 15 Feb 2021 09:32:51 GMT; Max-Age=86400/,/TB_DC_Flap_Test=0; Path=/; Domain=walmart.com; Expires=Sun, 14 Feb 2021 10:32:51 GMT; Max-Age=3600/,/vtc=Rhk42QOR0Wmu4R452HwYkE;Path=/;Domain=.walmart.com;Expires=Fri, 14 Feb 2031 21:32:51 GMT;Max-Age=315576000/,/bstc=Rhk42QOR0Wmu4R452HwYkE;Path=/;Domain=.walmart.com;Expires=Sun, 14 Feb 2021 10:02:51 GMT;Max-Age=1800/,/mobileweb=0; Path=/; Domain=walmart.com; Expires=Sun, 14 Feb 2021 10:02:51 GMT; Max-Age=1800/,/xpa=1wERM|5Z16k|bfyXO|np1Pu|piMFH; Path=/; Domain=walmart.com; Expires=Sun, 14 Feb 2021 10:02:51 GMT; Max-Age=1800/,/xpm=0%2B1613295171%2BRhk42QOR0Wmu4R452HwYkE~%2B0; Path=/; Domain=walmart.com; Expires=Sun, 14 Feb 2021 10:02:51 GMT; Max-Age=1800/,/exp-ck=bfyXO1; Path=/; Domain=walmart.com; Expires=Sun, 14 Feb 2021 10:02:51 GMT; Max-Age=1800/,/TS01b0be75=01538efd7cd0dba2bd4710700bc152f3514f1a97eb0b905564c5e97a2308f494c0a937c315a9f337bd1769571591556833993841c0; Path=/; Domain=.www.walmart.com/,/TS013ed49a=01538efd7cd0dba2bd4710700bc152f3514f1a97eb0b905564c5e97a2308f494c0a937c315a9f337bd1769571591556833993841c0; path=/; domain=walmart.com"

wm_ul_plus = find_between(data,'wm_ul_plus=',';')
auth = find_between(data,'auth=',';')
rtoken = find_between(data,'rtoken=',';')
spid = find_between(data,'SPID=',';')
cid = find_between(data,'CID=',';')
hascid = find_between(data,'hasCID=',';')
customer = find_between(data,'customer=',';')
type = find_between(data,'type=',';')
wmp = find_between(data,'WMP=',';')
slToken = find_between(data,'slToken=',';')
oneapp_customer = find_between(data,'oneapp_customer=',';')
TB_Latency_Tracker_100 = find_between(data,'TB_Latency_Tracker_100=',';')
TB_Navigation_Preload_01 = find_between(data,'TB_Navigation_Preload_01=',';')
TB_DC_Flap_Test = find_between(data,'TB_DC_Flap_Test=',';')
vtc = find_between(data,'vtc=',';')
bstc = find_between(data,'bstc=',';')
mobileweb = find_between(data,'mobileweb=',';')
xpa = find_between(data,'xpa=',';')
xpm = find_between(data,'xpm=',';')
expck = find_between(data,'exp-ck=',';')
TS01b0be75 = find_between(data,'TS01b0be75=',';')
TS013ed49a = find_between(data,'TS013ed49a=',';')

cookies = {
    'wm_ul_plus':wm_ul_plus,
    'auth':auth,
    'rtoken':rtoken,
    'SPID':spid,
    'CID':cid,
    'hasCID':hascid,
    'customer':customer,
    'type':type,
    'WMP':wmp,
    'slToken':slToken,
    'oneapp_customer':oneapp_customer,
    'TB_Latency_Tracker_100':TB_Latency_Tracker_100,
    'TB_Navigation_Preload_01':TB_Navigation_Preload_01,
    'TB_DC_Flap_Test':TB_DC_Flap_Test,
    'vtc':vtc,
    'bstc':bstc,
    'mobileweb':mobileweb,
    'xpa':xpa,
    'xpm':xpm,
    'exp-ck':expck,
    'TS01b0be75':TS01b0be75,
    'TS013ed49a':TS013ed49a
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `split` method?

Comment: had to do manually. As I said, the characters were repeating at unnecessary positions. So, I had to to manually.

Comment: If you have an answer to your question, please add it as an answer instead of editing it into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def find_between(s, first, last):
    try:
        start = s.index(first) + len(first)
        end = s.index(last, start)
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return False

data =  "wm_ul_plus=INACTIVE|1613381571686; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Mon, 14 Feb 2022 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; SameSite=LAX; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/auth=MTAyOTYyMDE4RUUxlsaiphCIYphVuNp1cW8dYFFyMJIbZ8DpbWT8qFqXUDp9UK0SuJbhcel7WWkve5Rje21UFFM0bpxMqABtRTreKh7yCzxu8zVUwgzKsi52faNy4xK57I8j8gR%2FH852oHOs%2FstByN418DB3KSmMotPVleFVli5P1islDQzG7NvR4D%2FWel8G5u4D%2FKZuF1GZ0lpexIPdqnQwv7yAOsfFnWxVon1qX0ChQbDsykETs9jg9b5uIWpUVgkjQM%2F2HhqZcy8EOh6rgyD2lIWedWfYuiCmiCCv7uWeLT7owCHMkcJn5z6CDUQq0VRZxYrvBKWfudWdVmyzjyYG1ezlt%2BK%2FXzVveqGzNst19qXpVJMKowcGagQ%2BHDIopDoHbqbNGWhqdr0cAS%2B8b8QaKTuPRQvC8A%3D%3D; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Mon, 14 Feb 2022 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; HttpOnly; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/rtoken=MDgyNTUyMDE4cvAeVJ1s78Vnw4eesakndgcpAMTqAgcZzWhFeUMjJIkVESjrGL3t0ar6VME0rt5lWm2XnQufGVK4GchMVN9rTooMGd6hdQrncJnF4VUykW2GPdOrmoVdnaSnkEaB1oxkrM8WSQCJm4CKPwlXkTpf9CNNbTHRvTAft1QZSfcthEl%2Bfli9I6HKjyyL%2BM%2F1vtiKOONMAYP1o3Jpf83qBCUd35qPky0K6hHbyYd6PaYhlqIGlcPPS8R00qN%2BhNiLcApQIcu5eoH0LLfpaagTy7Xeje99cBiCQvaFuqLDzwZsMdrJTVL1F4AGdny%2FqrbGRms%2FRAaBsGXYjXIWyIkbC104F2Y%2FJLJ5JsiMjD6VOKSTwZJ7fXmi3hvYzjb4clXbEkUbUMdZbTmJW1qBxQgwbE78Pw%3D%3D; Max-Age=2592000; Expires=Tue, 16 Mar 2021 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/SPID=d6266476ca903157e0e660433a3aa7346bca664f9a9490400cc20c8032ae3e4d4029a5d079c4aac3e3934eede0ce5161wmjet; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Mon, 14 Feb 2022 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; HttpOnly; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/CID=f20e6b0e-dfe8-1a52-e044-001517f43a86; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Mon, 14 Feb 2022 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/hasCID=1; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Mon, 14 Feb 2022 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/customer=%7B%22firstName%22%3A%22francine%22%2C%22lastNameInitial%22%3A%22b%22%2C%22rememberme%22%3Atrue%7D; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Mon, 14 Feb 2022 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/type=REGISTERED; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Mon, 14 Feb 2022 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; HttpOnly; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/WMP=4; Max-Age=15552000; Expires=Fri, 13 Aug 2021 09:32:51 GMT; SameSite=Lax; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/slToken=x; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; SameSite=Strict; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/oneapp_customer=true; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Mon, 14 Feb 2022 09:32:51 GMT; Secure; Domain=.walmart.com; Path=//,/TB_Latency_Tracker_100=1; Path=/; Domain=walmart.com; Expires=Mon, 15 Feb 2021 09:32:51 GMT; Max-Age=86400/,/TB_Navigation_Preload_01=1; Path=/; Domain=walmart.com; Expires=Mon, 15 Feb 2021 09:32:51 GMT; Max-Age=86400/,/TB_SFOU-100=; Path=/; Domain=walmart.com; Expires=Mon, 15 Feb 2021 09:32:51 GMT; Max-Age=86400/,/TB_DC_Flap_Test=0; Path=/; Domain=walmart.com; Expires=Sun, 14 Feb 2021 10:32:51 GMT; Max-Age=3600/,/vtc=Rhk42QOR0Wmu4R452HwYkE;Path=/;Domain=.walmart.com;Expires=Fri, 14 Feb 2031 21:32:51 GMT;Max-Age=315576000/,/bstc=Rhk42QOR0Wmu4R452HwYkE;Path=/;Domain=.walmart.com;Expires=Sun, 14 Feb 2021 10:02:51 GMT;Max-Age=1800/,/mobileweb=0; Path=/; Domain=walmart.com; Expires=Sun, 14 Feb 2021 10:02:51 GMT; Max-Age=1800/,/xpa=1wERM|5Z16k|bfyXO|np1Pu|piMFH; Path=/; Domain=walmart.com; Expires=Sun, 14 Feb 2021 10:02:51 GMT; Max-Age=1800/,/xpm=0%2B1613295171%2BRhk42QOR0Wmu4R452HwYkE~%2B0; Path=/; Domain=walmart.com; Expires=Sun, 14 Feb 2021 10:02:51 GMT; Max-Age=1800/,/exp-ck=bfyXO1; Path=/; Domain=walmart.com; Expires=Sun, 14 Feb 2021 10:02:51 GMT; Max-Age=1800/,/TS01b0be75=01538efd7cd0dba2bd4710700bc152f3514f1a97eb0b905564c5e97a2308f494c0a937c315a9f337bd1769571591556833993841c0; Path=/; Domain=.www.walmart.com/,/TS013ed49a=01538efd7cd0dba2bd4710700bc152f3514f1a97eb0b905564c5e97a2308f494c0a937c315a9f337bd1769571591556833993841c0; path=/; domain=walmart.com"

wm_ul_plus = find_between(data,'wm_ul_plus=',';')
auth = find_between(data,'auth=',';')
rtoken = find_between(data,'rtoken=',';')
spid = find_between(data,'SPID=',';')
cid = find_between(data,'CID=',';')
hascid = find_between(data,'hasCID=',';')
customer = find_between(data,'customer=',';')
type = find_between(data,'type=',';')
wmp = find_between(data,'WMP=',';')
slToken = find_between(data,'slToken=',';')
oneapp_customer = find_between(data,'oneapp_customer=',';')
TB_Latency_Tracker_100 = find_between(data,'TB_Latency_Tracker_100=',';')
TB_Navigation_Preload_01 = find_between(data,'TB_Navigation_Preload_01=',';')
TB_DC_Flap_Test = find_between(data,'TB_DC_Flap_Test=',';')
vtc = find_between(data,'vtc=',';')
bstc = find_between(data,'bstc=',';')
mobileweb = find_between(data,'mobileweb=',';')
xpa = find_between(data,'xpa=',';')
xpm = find_between(data,'xpm=',';')
expck = find_between(data,'exp-ck=',';')
TS01b0be75 = find_between(data,'TS01b0be75=',';')
TS013ed49a = find_between(data,'TS013ed49a=',';')

cookies = {
    'wm_ul_plus':wm_ul_plus,
    'auth':auth,
    'rtoken':rtoken,
    'SPID':spid,
    'CID':cid,
    'hasCID':hascid,
    'customer':customer,
    'type':type,
    'WMP':wmp,
    'slToken':slToken,
    'oneapp_customer':oneapp_customer,
    'TB_Latency_Tracker_100':TB_Latency_Tracker_100,
    'TB_Navigation_Preload_01':TB_Navigation_Preload_01,
    'TB_DC_Flap_Test':TB_DC_Flap_Test,
    'vtc':vtc,
    'bstc':bstc,
    'mobileweb':mobileweb,
    'xpa':xpa,
    'xpm':xpm,
    'exp-ck':expck,
    'TS01b0be75':TS01b0be75,
    'TS013ed49a':TS013ed49a
}
```

I just manually did.